# File explorer (Windows) that displays (GUI) a numbered column next to file list

Tags: file-management

I am looking for a file explorer (or Windows Explorer trick/addon/whatever) that will display a column of numbers, in increasing order as you descend, on the left margin of your viewing window. I an **not** looking for a file explorer that will tell you the size of a folder, the size of a particular file, or the total number of files in a folder; I want a numbered list view that does not alter filenames.  You probably know exactly what I mean but here is a screenshot from Notepad++ (note a file explorer, sadly) that shows an analogous feature next to a list of personal names.

[image]

Thank you.